# How to prove a set with at least one element is a separator?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Lawvere's *Sets for Mathematics* and got stuck at Exercise 1.15

> In the category of abstract sets S, any set A with at least one element $1 \xrightarrow{x} A$ is a separator.

I can see that with the axiom that "the terminal object $1$ is a separator" and the following diagram, I ought to deduce the statement, but I cannot seem to write it down formally:

[image: graph](![enter image description here])

Any hint please?

Answer (score 6):

**Definition**. An object $S$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a separator if and only if whenever

$$f_1,f_2:X\rightrightarrows Y$$
are arrows of $\mathcal{C}$ then
$$(\forall x[S\overset{x} \rightarrow X \Rightarrow f_1 x = f_2 x])\Longrightarrow f_1 = f_2 $$
in other words
$$f_1 \neq f_2 \Longrightarrow (\exists x[S\overset{x} \rightarrow X \hspace{0.3cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.3cm} f_1 x \neq f_2 x)$$

- THE TERMINAL OBJECT $1$ SEPARATES MAPPINGS IN $\mathcal{Set}.$

A one-element set $1$ is a separator in $\mathcal{S}$, i.e., if

$$f_1,f_2:X\rightrightarrows Y$$
then
$$(\forall x[1\overset{x} \rightarrow X \Rightarrow f_1 x = f_2 x])\Longrightarrow f_1 = f_2 $$

in other words
$$f_1 \neq f_2 \Longrightarrow (\exists x[1\overset{x} \rightarrow X \hspace{0.3cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.3cm} f_1 x \neq f_2 x)$$
**Statement**. In the category of abstract sets $\mathcal{Set}$, any set $A$ with at least one element $1\overset{x}\rightarrow A $ is also a separator.

**Proof**.

Suppose $f_1 \neq f_2$. Then $1$ separates them, there exists  $1\overset{x} \rightarrow X$ such that $f_1 x \neq f_2 x$ 
$$1\overset{x}\rightarrow X\rightrightarrows Y$$
$A$ is a separator if and only if there exists $h:A\to X$ s.t. $f_1 h \neq f_2 h$. Consider $h = x\circ !$
$$A\overset{!}\to 1\overset{x}\rightarrow X\rightrightarrows Y$$
Let's show that $f_1 \circ x\circ !\neq f_2 \circ x\circ !$.
Consider any element $1\overset{a}\to A$, it separates $f_1 \circ x\circ !$ and $ f_2 \circ x\circ !$
$$1\overset{a}\to A\overset{!}\to 1\overset{x}\rightarrow X\rightrightarrows Y$$
because $1\overset{a}\to A\overset{!}\to 1$ is $id_1$ identity arrow of $1$ 
$$f_1\circ x \circ ! \circ a = f_1\circ x \neq f_2\circ x = f_2\circ x \circ ! \circ a$$
Hence $$f_1 \circ x\circ !\neq f_2 \circ x\circ !$$ and $A$ is a separator.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be any non-empty set. If $f,g:A\to B$ are two functions with $f\neq g$, then $f(a)\neq g(a)$ for some $a\in A$. Now choose an element $x\in X$ and define a function $h:X\to A$ such that $h(x)=a$. Then $fh\neq gh$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lawvere's book, but I take it that he, as Johnstone, takes "separator" to mean what other categorical sources call ["generator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(category_theory)) . If it is not the case, then tell me and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Yeah, "separator"=generator in this book.

Comment: I can get  $f \circ h(x) = g \circ h(x)$;   But does  $f \circ h\neq g \circ h$  follow immediately from that?

Comment: So a separator object  $S$ for  $f_1, f_2: X \rightarrow Y$ satisfies: $f_1 \neq f_2 \Longrightarrow \exists a [S  \xrightarrow{a} X \Longrightarrow f_1 a \neq f_2 a]$.  Right?

Comment: @Problemania: $f(a)\neq g(a) \Rightarrow f\circ h(x)\neq g\circ h (x)$ since $a=h(x)$. Hence the two functions $f\circ h$ and $g\circ h$ are different at the element $x\in X$. If two functions differ in one point, then they are different, by definition of equality of functions! As for your second comment, yes, exactly, that's actually the definition of generator (or a slight rewording of it).

Comment: Also, be careful, you say "a separator object for $f_1,f_2$", but that's not right. A separator is a separator *for the category*, and it satisfies the condition you wrote *for every* $f_1,f_2$.

Comment: @BrunoStonek, thanks for reminding me of that.  That's exactly right. A separator is for a category, and it separates any pair of two different morphisms. I'm trying to I've finally written down the reasoning more formally as a [note](http://j.mp/pseperator).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what happens if $f_1 h=f_2 h$ for every $h:A\to X$? Particularly, if $f_1\neq f_2$ and $i:1\to X$ separates them, what about $i\circ !:A\to 1\to X$?

Comment: I've not read enough to be introduced the symbol $!$.  What does it represent?  A quick Web search did not help.

Comment: Sorry! It's just the unique arrow $A\to 1$. It's the first notation I was introduced to for it, and I never have figured out what's standard, so I keep using it :p

Comment: What's the meaning of putting a circle *after* $i \circ$? Evgeny Kuznetsov also has a circle after $x \circ$. Does that indicate a particular element as opposed to a map or arrow?

Comment: @PédeLeão - $\circ$ is a common binary operator for composition. Sometimes authors skip it and just use juxtaposition, but sometimes I find it clearer to write. But "$i\circ$" is an incomplete expression that doesn't mean anything above -- it's "$i\circ !$" that's the real expression.

Comment: OK. The idea that $!$ is actually an arrow wasn't quite computing with me, so I didn't see it as a composition. Thanks.

Comment: @User4407 By the way, more generally, sometimes you may find $!$ used to represent uniqueness of something. It naturally corresponds to the unique map from any set to singleton.